# Moving files with UNC destination path in Celery task

Tags: python, django, celery, shutil

I'm currently trying to transfer a file as a Celery Task on Django from local disk to another machine via UNC path and I've run into quite a few road blocks.

I've used a package called [win_unc](http://covenanteyes.github.io/py_win_unc/) which works fine in an independent script. However when I use the same code as a celery task, I run into the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\task\trace.py", line 228, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\task\trace.py", line 415, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Path\to\file\file.py", line 96, in movefile
    conn.mount()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win_unc\connecting.py", line 163, in mount
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win_unc\connecting.py", line 63, in connect
    self._connect_with_creds(self.get_username(), self.get_password())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win_unc\connecting.py", line 118, in _connect_with_creds
    run(command)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win_unc\internal\shell.py", line 29, in run
    raise ShellCommandError(command, process.returncode)
ShellCommandError: The command `NET USE "Y:" "\\UNC\path" /PERSISTENT:NO` exited with error code 2.
```

The other modules I used to move the file were os and shutil.

I used shutil to copy the file over to the UNC destination and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\task\trace.py", line 228, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\task\trace.py", line 415, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Path\to\file\file.py", line 96, in movefile
    shutil.copy(source.strip(), dest.strip())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 117, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: '\\\\UNC\\path\\somefile.csv'
```

This was error with os.rename

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\task\trace.py", line 228, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\celery\task\trace.py", line 415, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Path\to\file\file.py", line 95, in movefile
    os.rename(source, dest)
WindowsError: [Error 1326] Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password
```

All of the above work fine when I use an independent python script to move the file. This also works from the python command line. I don't understand why it fails as a Celery task or if there is any other reason.

I use Python 2.7.3 and Django 1.4.2.

I'd really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Solution: I just created an independent application to take care of transferring files. Somehow the Celery task wrapper doesn't allow for windows commands.

Comment: Sadly I'm not very familiar with Windows, but maybe it has not setup the environment properly to execute these commands?  E.g. maybe it is not associated with user privileges.

Comment: The environment was set up correctly and works perfectly with other applications and independent scripts. The only difference is that they aren't wrapped inside a celery task like the code above.